# Session variables not saving

Tags: model-view-controller, forms, authentication, appfabric

I have MVC application which uses Forms authentication. For some reason any session variable that I declare are not saving whenever the user is not logged in. My application needs to support both authenticated and unauthenticated users. The applications works fine when ran locally. The issue only occurs on our remote server. We're using appfabric for session state. I'm trying trouble shoot the issue but I don't know where to start. Any advice would be welcomed!

Edit-when I change the value for httpCookies domain = "future.domain.com" to httpCookies domain="" it works fine. I was told by our admins that we need this setting to not change.

Answer (score 0):

11 years later but if is still usefull for anybody there, sometimes this happend if you have more than one project of mvc open, i dont know why but that usually happened to me, just close the projects that are not in use and try again, if this still does not work, just try to reset visual studio or your computer